# How to return FilePathResult content to a View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rendering, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I have a View that I want to use the return value from another method in the Controller.Example:

```
public class PdfController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Pdf/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public FileResult PdfAsContent()
        {
            return File(@"C:\Users\...\english.pdf","application/pdf");
        }
    }
```

When I navigate to **localhost/Pdf/PdfAsContent** it successfully loads the content of the PDF but I want to load it as a part of a View.I want to have a lable and under it to show what is show by the:**localhost/Pdf/PdfAsContent**

I tried with:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<div>
    @Url.Action("PdfAsContent")
</div>
```

But it returns :
Index
pdf/PdfAsContent

Comment: I think you will probably have to load the PDF in an `iFrame` for it to display *with* other content.

Comment: I tried it but it depends on the browser.It worked for me only on IE10 but Chrome and Mozilla couldn't render it.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) for this. You will need to set `embedded=true` in the url for this.

For example, if you wanted to view the PDF at the URL http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf ,you would use the URL: http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf

- All viewer URLs should use the path http://docs.google.com/viewer . This path accepts two parameters:
- url : The URL of the document to view. This should be URL-encoded.
- embedded : If set to true , the viewer will use an embedded mode interface.